# merge if/ elseif statements into one php

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I have the following code which is almost the same all the time (about 50 times):

```
if ($product=='product1' || $product=='product1 + extra')
{
 mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO downloads (key, file, expires)VALUES ('{$strKey}', 'test.zip', '".(time()+(60*60*24*7))."')"); 
}
else if ($product=='product2' || $product=='product2 + extra')
{
 mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO downloads (key, file, expires)VALUES ('{$strKey}', 'test2.zip', '".(time()+(60*60*24*7))."')"); 
}
//else if () {}
```

The only things that are changing are the product and the file name (product1, product2, ecc.. + test.zip, test2.zip,ecc...).

So I was thinking about making two arrays with the product names and the file names and then looping through these arrays, but I have no idea if it's possible and how to change the code properly.

Does anybody know a good solution?

Thanks for helping and sorry for my English, it isn't perfect.

**EDIT**

product1, product2, ecc, test1.zip, test2.zip, ecc. are only placeholders for the real names which are changing and they are always different.

product1, product2 come from a $_POST which is selected from the user by some  options.

Comment: Just use regex to match `$product` and insert.  On insert, use prepared/parameterized queries... don't concatenate data directly into a query.  Also, for the timestamp if you want database server time, use the appropriate SQL for that rather than application server time.

Comment: Make it a function and call the same function. Code reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my own solution which is working:

```
$files = array(
'product1' => 'test.zip',
'product2' => 'test2.zip'
//other products and files
 );
```

After creating the array it's sufficient to create a loop like

```
foreach($files as $file => $name){
if($product == $file || $product == $file . ' + extra' ){
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO downloads (key, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', '$name', '".(time()+(60*60*24*7))."')"); 
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Roughly you want something like the following...

```
$count = 50;//This should be set using something such as count() on an object.
$i = 0;

while ($i<$count)
{
 if ($product=='product'.$i || $product=='product'.$i.' + extra')
 {
  $filename1 = strrev($product);
  $file = explode('.',$filename,2);
  $file_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"],strrev($file[1]));
  $file_ext = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"],strrev($file[0]));
  mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO downloads (key, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', $file_name.$i.'.'.$file_ext, '".(time()+(60*60*24*7))."')"); 
 }

 $i++;
}
```

You'll have to make sure that you assign the `$count` to something that  determines how many items you'll be dealing with. Also make sure the `while` loop iterates for as many items as you have (some people end up wondering why the last item isn't processed. If you provided more code I'd be able to give you a more spot-on example though I think you'll be able to handle it from here. Make sure that you are escaping data in those `INSERT` queries, again you've only provided a limited amount of code so it is possible you that you *are* escaping though it's important to make sure your code is secure. Lastly you may need to change `$i` to 1 instead of 0 subjective to your numbering scheme.

Comment: You forgot the counter in `test.zip`. Apart from that, this is the approach I would have wanted to write down in an answer, but you were quicker. :)

Comment: The name of the product isn't always the same and so for the name of the file. When the user is selecting a product and submit a form to download it, a one-time-download key is generated, and it will be submitted to the users mail adress. So only counting wouldn't be a solution i think.

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol, yeah FF11 didn't have a number in the first iteration hence the missing counter there.

Comment: @FF11 Did my answer work or do you need further help before you can accept the answer?

Comment: @John Please take a look at my previous comment. I haven't any idea how to implement it if the product name or the file name changes. I hope you understand my issue and my english. Also, with "about 50" i want to say that the number of products can be increased or decreased

Comment: @FF11 Somewhere you should be able to store the base file name to a variable and use that in place. I'm working with flat-files that my system generates and assigns an [epoch].xml file name/extension approach. Throw me a $variable and I'll edit my post or edit your question to include the code (if you can) where those file names are determined and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @John The name of the product is added dynamically with $_POST from a form. If the form is submitted, the link to the download of the product will be sent to the user. So it doesn't make any difference what $variable name to choose. The best should be an array with all product names and all file names. Hope you understand

Comment: @FF11 I've updated the code to handle the file names BUT since you did not clarify the **SPECIFIC** `$_POST` variable name you'll have to edit that yourself. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you. `$product = trim($_POST['product']);`, so the $product in my (your) code IS already the $_POST variable. I didn't post the whole code because there are more files involved. So `if ($product=='product1'` IS already the `$_POST['product']`. Also the product names inside the `$_POST['product']` names are changing because the user select to download the products from a <select> which passes the value. Hope now it's clearer. Sorry for my english :-((.

Comment: Well just replace the `$_POST['product']` with `$product`; I just edited the answer again to reflect that. Not sure where you are though at this point, after making the change I am talking about in *this* comment do you have it working or is there anther issue? Your English is fine, I think it is more about getting a grip on the dynamics of the code; dynamic code is more difficult but once you really grasp it then your life will be so much easier. :-)

Comment: I still don't understand where to add the various product names and the related files. You wrote `if ($product=='product'.$i`, but "if ($product=='**product**'.$i" is always changing based on the users choice. Still trying to really understand your code which appears a little bit complicated for me :-((. For example i have 10 product names ($product=='**product**') like "good book", "very good book", "bad book", ecc. and 10 related file names like "file1.zip", "file2.zip", ecc. Where should i store the file names and the files itself ? This is really confusing me :-((

Comment: It sounds like you may need an associative array: `array('file1.zip'=>'good book','file2.zip'=>'bad book');` though that is going outside of the scope of how you posted the question. You'll need to edit your question to include as much *relevant* information otherwise we may soon discover the comment limit here on Stack.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I need/ want to include an array in my code. I mentioned it at the beginning of my question. The necessary piece of code is all there. I cannot provide the whole form + ALL the related php code. I think the necessary code is there. However i will edit my question a little bit. Anyway, thanks a lot!